# When is providing local sections enough to give the structure of a fiber bundle?

Tags: differential-geometry, fiber-bundles

Let $\pi: E \rightarrow B$ be a surjective continuous map of topological spaces. Suppose we have an open cover of $B$ such that each set $U$ in the cover admits a continuous section $s: U \rightarrow E$. Are there some (well-known/common) general conditions under which these sections guarantee that $E$ is a fiber bundle? What about a principal $G$-bundle with $G$ a topological group acting continuously on $E$? What about the smooth case?

What motivated me to ask is that I encountered the statement "we can show directly that $S^{2n+1} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}P^n$ is locally trivial by producing sections over an open cover", which in general doesn't seem at all obvious to me, and in this case seems to depend on seeing $\mathbb{C}P^n$ as the orbit space of $S^{2n+1}$ acted on by $S^1$ and on the fact that this action is free, which is already begging the question.

Comment: One section suffices when it's going to be a principal bundle. But how many do you need for a general vector bundle or fiber bundle?

Comment: You mean one section per open set in the cover suffices to be able to say that we have a fiber bundle? Could you elaborate on why that it?

Comment: No, no. I'm questioning that completely. When you have a principal bundle, a single section gives a trivialization. But in general, I'm asking you what you hope for. Certainly a single section won't tell us much.

Comment: For the quote that motivated the question, $S^1$ (viewed as the multiplicative group of unit complex numbers) acts on the complex Euclidean space by scalar multiplication. This action clearly (i) preserves the norm, hence the unit sphere; (ii) is free; and (iii) has the complex projective space as orbit space. Maybe this is to say, viewing $S^{2n+1}$ as the total space of a circle bundle over $\mathbf{CP}^n$ is not some esoteric observation. :) Anyway, as Ted notes, finding one section of this surjection over each affine coordinate neighborhood shows we have a principal $S^1$ bundle.